# Shifting a PySpark dataframe column by a variable value in another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a PySpark dataframe that looks like this

| Date | Value | Shift_Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/02/11 | 50.12 | 0 |
| 2021/02/12 | 72.30 | 4 |
| 2021/02/15 | 81.87 | 1 |
| 2021/02/16 | 90.12 | 2 |
| 2021/02/17 | 91.31 | 1 |
| 2021/02/18 | 81.23 | 2 |
| 2021/02/19 | 73.45 | 1 |
| 2021/02/22 | 87.17 | 0 |

I want to lead the offset (On the basis of the values in the Shift_Index column here) which I have to pass depends on a particular Column of type Integer.
Can we somehow use an offset value that depends on the column value in lead/lag function in spark SQL ?
I wanted somewhat like this, which works fine in SQL server, but unfortunately throws exception in Spark SQL.

```
Create table test_table(ID int identity(1,1), Value float, shift_col int, New_Value float)

SELECT Value, shift_col,
ISNULL(LEAD(Value, shift_col) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC), Value) AS New_Value
FROM test_table
```

The final result that I need looks something similar to this :

| Date | Value | Shift_Index | New_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/02/11 | 50.12 | 0 | 50.12 |
| 2021/02/12 | 72.30 | 4 | 81.23 |
| 2021/02/15 | 81.87 | 1 | 90.12 |
| 2021/02/16 | 90.12 | 2 | 81.23 |
| 2021/02/17 | 91.31 | 1 | 81.23 |
| 2021/02/18 | 81.23 | 2 | 87.17 |
| 2021/02/19 | 73.45 | 1 | 87.17 |
| 2021/02/22 | 87.17 | 0 | 87.17 |

The following exceptions are encountered

- Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o77.sql.
- : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'lead(sample_data_temp.`shift_col`, NULL)' due to data type mismatch: Offset expression 'shift_col#2835' must be a literal

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a spark use case.

Comment: Can be done but nedc to think outside of the box.

Comment: Will your dataframe be always ordered by `Date`?

Comment: @snithish : Yes, the dataframe will always be ordered by `Date`

Answer (score 0):

You could do so with a window and lead. If you have very spread out values for Shift_index you could do a select distinct to determine which shifts you need instead of everything up to the max shift.

Ideally you have something to partition your window by otherwise this can be very heavy for large datasets. Spark provides a warning:

`WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.`

Edit: solution without join, still not partitioning means this doesn't parallelize well.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().orderBy(f.col('Date'))

max_shift = df.agg(f.max('Shift_index')).collect()[0][0]

for shift in range(1, max_shift+1):
    df = df.withColumn('Value' + str(shift), f.lead(f.col('Value'), shift).over(w))

case_shift = 'CASE Shift_index WHEN 0 THEN Value ' + ' '.join([f'WHEN {i} THEN Value{i}' for i in range(1, max_shift + 1)]) + ' ELSE NULL END'

df = df.select(
    f.col('Date'),
    f.col('Shift_index'),
    f.col('Value'),
    f.expr(case_shift).alias('New_Value')
)

df.show()

+----------+-----+-----------+---------+                                        
|      Date|Value|Shift_index|New_Value|
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+
|2021/02/11|50.12|          0|    50.12|
|2021/02/12| 72.3|          4|    81.23|
|2021/02/15|81.87|          1|    90.12|
|2021/02/16|90.12|          2|    81.23|
|2021/02/17|91.31|          1|    81.23|
|2021/02/18|81.23|          2|    87.17|
|2021/02/19|73.45|          1|    87.17|
|2021/02/22|87.17|          0|    87.17|
+----------+-----+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: At scal how would this perform?

Comment: Not very well I'm afraid, the problem as is in the question doesn't parallelize well. But its hard to judge if the use case is not known. Spark helpfully provides a warning which I shall add to the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Indeed so u need to do it differently.

Comment: You're free to add your answer

Comment: But interested to see if u can...

Comment: @ScootCork : Thanks for the solution. Please note, the implementation is for near real time data. Will it not be extremely computationally expensive considering Spark architecture?

Comment: I cannot answer that question for you, it depends on different factors. All I can say is that the problem as you asked it doesn't parallelize well so Spark is not ideal. I think this is what thebluephantom also meant by 'Not a Spark use case'

Comment: Indeed. It can be done, but if near real time you need to see if possible with sp str streaming. U should have stated near real time as well. @MainakMaitra